# SQL query to retrieve data from one table depending on data stored in another table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

There are 3 tables: table1, table2 and table3.

The query is:

```
select column1 from table1 where variable1=@value1 AND variable2=@value2
```

Here, value1 and value2 are the whole data stored in tables table2 and table3

Comment: this question is not very clear - it may be worth editing it to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear but the closest guess would be

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.variable1 = table2.value1
JOIN table3 ON table1.variable2 = table3.value2
```

Comment: value1 and value2 have multiple values form table2 and table3

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select colum1
from table1
where
    variable1 in (select column2 from table2) and
    variable2 in (select column3 from table3)
```